# Passing a mutable object in a function as default argument - Curious behavior

Tags: python, default-value

Please take a gander at this `function` with a mutable object `list` as a default argument:

```
def foo(x, items = []):
    items.append(x)
    return items
foo(1)      #returns [1]
foo(2)      #returns [1,2]
foo(3)      #returns [1,2,3]
```

I am curious as to why does this happen? I mean I have read that a `function's` scope is terminated as soon as it finishes execution, so the `items` in the first call must have been destroyed after the first call. I then tried to check if the `items` was in global scope.

```
>>> print(items)
>>> Traceback (most recent call 
    File "c:\Users\GauriShanker\Desktop\mypython\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(items)
    NameError: name 'items' is not defined.
```

Turns out it is not. 
I am curious as to :

1. why was not the `items` variable destroyed after every call. As is evident clearly, every successive function call is picking the value of the `items` variable from the last function call. If the `items` variable is not in global scope, where does it live and why?
2. When I have not explicitly provided the second arguement in function calls, should it not just make `items` equal to `[]` as the default value. Isn't the whole point of declaring the default parameters? It does set `items` to `[]` only in the first call but not in the second and third call.

Please guide.

Comment: This is almost exactly the same question as the duplicate. Have you read through that yet?

Comment: The default parameter objects are attached to the function, so they *don't* get destroyed after the call. Remember that a function is an object too.

Comment: One more thing, objects in Python can have multiple references. You're correct that `items` goes out of scope, but that's only one reference to the object. There's another reference held by the function object so the object itself never gets destroyed.

Comment: @MarkRansom I understand that but shouldn't `items` variable be set to `[]` every time I call the function without the second argument?

Comment: No, because that assignment is only evaluated once, when the function is defined. It isn't evaluated at every function call.